# How to run a batch file in a remote machine from the Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I am building a C# project and deployed the package using Teamcity.

I have added a step in the build configuration that I need to execute a batch file present in the remote machine.

The batch file is copied to the remote machine along with the deployed package.

I am getting the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: can you specify what command/script are you using to run it

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly entering the path of the batch file, it will look for the same path on teamcity server and not on the remote machine.

you would have to install psexec on team city machine. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

This command will help you to execute the script on remote machine

Now create a Command line step like this[image: Teamcity runner type]

and then in custom script use following :-

psexec \10.0.111.111 -d -accepteula -u domainname\userid -p password cmd.exe "Path/To/BatchFile.bat"

Here *10.0.111.111* is the ip adress of remote machine(Can use hostname as well).
*domainname\userid* is domain name and user id used to login the remote machine.
*password* is the password used to login remote machine.
*Path/To/BatchFile.bat* is the path to the batch file.